# IllegalArgumentException when computing a PCA with Spark ML

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a parquet file containing the `id` and `features` columns and I want to apply the pca algorithm.

```
val dataset =  spark.read.parquet("/usr/local/spark/dataset/data/user")
val features = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(Array("id", "features" ))
    .setOutputCol("features")
val pca = new PCA()
     .setInputCol("features")
     .setK(50)
     .fit(dataset)
     .setOutputCol("pcaFeatures")
val result = pca.transform(dataset).select("pcaFeatures")
pca.save("/usr/local/spark/dataset/out")
```

but I have this exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column features must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 but was actually ArrayType(DoubleType,true).

Comment: Can you show us the result of `dataset.printSchema` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark's PCA transformer needs a column created by a `VectorAssembler`. Here you create one but never use it. Also, the `VectorAssembler` only takes numbers as input. I don't know what the type of `features` is, but if it's an array, it won't work. Transform it into numeric columns first. Finally, it is a bad idea to name the assembled column the same way as an original column. Indeed, the `VectorAssembler` does not remove input columns and you will end up if two `features` columns.

Here is a working example of PCA computation in Spark:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature._

val df = spark.range(10)
    .select('id, ('id * 'id) as "id2", ('id * 'id * 'id) as "id3")
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(Array("id", "id2", "id3")).setOutputCol("features")
val assembled_df = assembler.transform(df)
val pca = new PCA()
    .setInputCol("features").setOutputCol("pcaFeatures").setK(2)
    .fit(assembled_df)
val result = pca.transform(assembled_df)
```