# Exception:features must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to run pca with KNN in spark. I have a file that contains id, features.

```
> KNN.printSchema
root
|-- id: int (nullable = true)
|-- features: double (nullable = true)
```

code:

```
val dataset =  spark.read.parquet("/usr/local/spark/dataset/data/user")
val features = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(Array("id", "features" ))
    .setOutputCol("features")
val Array(train, test) = dataset
      .randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3), seed = 1234L)
      .map(_.cache())

//create PCA matrix to reduce feature dimensions
val pca = new PCA()
      .setInputCol("features")
      .setK(5)
      .setOutputCol("pcaFeatures")
val knn = new KNNClassifier()
      .setTopTreeSize(dataset.count().toInt / 5)
      .setFeaturesCol("pcaFeatures")
      .setPredictionCol("predicted")
      .setK(1)
val pipeline = new Pipeline()
      .setStages(Array(pca, knn))
      .fit(train)
```

Above code block is throwing this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column features must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 but was actually ArrayType(DoubleType,true).
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnType(SchemaUtils.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.PCAParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(PCA.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.PCAModel.validateAndTransformSchema(PCA.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.PCAModel.transformSchema(PCA.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$transformSchema$4.apply(Pipeline.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$transformSchema$4.apply(Pipeline.scala:180)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:57)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:66)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foldLeft(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline.fit(Pipeline.scala:132)
    at KNN$.main(KNN.scala:63)
    at KNN.main(KNN.scala)
```

Comment: Can you provide the result of `dataset.printSchema` please? Btw, your question looks a lot like another you asked a few days ago. You cound not solve the previous problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59922124/illegalargumentexception-when-computing-a-pca-with-spark-ml

Comment: yes,I solved problem with pca algorithm but when using with knn and pipeline It's appear again.what's wrong

Comment: It is more or less the same issue as before. Can you print the result of `dataset.printSchema` ? Also, you are trying to run a classification. What is the label?

Comment: there is something I can't understand I try to run knn only but another error appear " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "label" does not exist".

Comment: Right, you need to specify a label to train a classifier, and you did not. That was the point of my previous question. What are you trying to predict?

Comment: I want to predict top n ratings of movies for 20m movielens dataset to solve cold start problem in recommendation system.

Comment: But your dataset here only contains an id and a feature... is it a mock dataset?

Comment: No,It consists of three files ratings,movies,tags.I worked on ratings file and applied ALS algorithm. id ,features as result of ALS algorithm.

Comment: I wrote an answer with a generic way to do classification in spark, and fixing what was wrong in your code. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are trying to split the dataset into training and test, assemble features, run a PCA and then a classifier to predict something. The overall logic is correct but there are several problems with your code.

1. A PCA in spark needs assembled features. You created one but you do not use it in the code.
2. You gave the name `features` to the output of the assembler, and you already have a column named that way. Since you do not use it, you don't see an error but if you were you would get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Output column features already exists.
```

3. When running a classification, you need to specify at the very least the input features with `setFeaturesCol` and the label you are trying to learn with `setLabelCol`. You did not specified the label and by default, the label is `"label"`. You don't have any column named that way, hence the exception spark throws at you.

Here is a working example of what you are trying to do.

```scala
// a funky dataset with 3 features (`x1`, `x2`, `x`3) and a label `y`,
// the class we are trying to predict.
val dataset = spark.range(10)
    .select('id as "x1", rand() as "x2", ('id * 'id) as "x3")
    .withColumn("y", (('x2 * 3 + 'x1) cast "int").mod(2))
    .cache()

// splitting the dataset, that part was ok ;-)
val Array(train, test) = dataset
      .randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3), seed = 1234L)
      .map(_.cache())

// An assembler, the output name cannot be one of the inputs.
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(Array("x1", "x2", "x3"))
    .setOutputCol("features")

// A pca, that part was ok as well
val pca = new PCA()
    .setInputCol("features")
    .setK(2)
    .setOutputCol("pcaFeatures")

// A LogisticRegression classifier. (KNN is not part of spark's standard API, but
// requires the same minimum information: features and label)
val classifier = new LogisticRegression()
    .setFeaturesCol("pcaFeatures")
    .setLabelCol("y")

// And the full pipeline
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(assembler, pca, classifier))
val model = pipeline.fit(train)
```

Comment: Add `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions_.`

Comment: Is it necessary to convert file to LibSVM?

Comment: About `x1`, I know it does not exist in your data. It was just en example. You have to replace `x1`, `x2`, `x3` by your features, and `y` by your label.

Comment: thanks so much.I'm sorry for late but value in rawPrediction is [Infinity,-Infinity],prediction is 0.0

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean.